# javafx preloader in springboot and maven

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, javafx, preloader

**How do I add that javafx preloader to be shown immediately when the user starts the application before all the spring and back-end magic?**

I am working on the project with maven springboot and javafx, I would like to add javafx preloader which I have created but I cannot succeed in any way. The only way that kind of worked was via setting jvm argument at run time like so: `Djavafx.preloader=com.preloader.MyFxPreloader`. The problem here was that the preloader screen appeared way too late and was visible only for few milliseconds. There was a lot of spring boot and back-end initialisation going on before this for couple of seconds but I could not see my preloader executing until the very last moment. Here is a code of my preloder (Only the main file, although I am pretty sure the issue has nothing to do with the code really):

```
public class MyFxPreloader extends Preloader {

private Stage stage;
private RudementaryController controller;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    this.controller = new RudementaryController();

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    URL resource =  getClass().getResource("/main.fxml");
    loader.setLocation(resource);
    loader.setController(controller);

    Parent root = loader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    this.stage = primaryStage;
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

@Override
public void handleProgressNotification(ProgressNotification pn) {
    controller.updateProgressBar(pn.getProgress());
}

@Override
public void handleStateChangeNotification(StateChangeNotification evt) {
    if (evt.getType() == StateChangeNotification.Type.BEFORE_START) {
        stage.hide();
    }
}
```

Project is built using using maven plugin: `spring-boot-maven-plugin` and here is my main (Project is a spring boot application):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LOGGER.info("Creating context");
        context = SpringApplication.run(Config.class, args);
        LOGGER.info("Context created");
        context.registerShutdownHook();
        PriceServer priceServer = context.getBean(HeadLessPriceServer.class);
        HealthMonitor healthMonitor = context.getBean(HealthMonitor.class);
        healthMonitor.setContext(context);

        try {

            LOGGER.info("main - start (starting server)");
            priceServer.start();
            LOGGER.info("main - start (started server)");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("main - start (encountered exception shutting down)", e);
            LOGGER.error("main - start (exiting with -1)");
            Platform.exit();
        }

        launch(args);
        context.close();
    }
}
```

I understand that I am calling javafx "launch" at the end of the main - but should I do it differently? **Basically, how do I add that javafx preloader to be shown immediately when the user starts the application before all the spring and back-end magic?**

Thank you in advance.

Ps. I know there are similar issues discussed online - I am pretty sure I have seen all of them - also none of them really discusses maven, spring boot and javafx preloaders combined. None of them really tells me how to combine it all together. Thanks you.

Comment: You shouldn't be putting anything in `main()` other than a call to `launch()`. Move the other code in `main()` to `start()` (or `init()`). (And call `context.close()` via `stop()`). Not played with preloaders much, so I don't know if that will fix everything, but I don't think your preloader starts until you call `launch()`, which would explain what you are currently seeing.